# how to drop predictable value (y) in python random forest model

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I run a random forest model in python to see the importance of features. However, the predictable value (y) cannot be dropped and it looks like it plays as one of the parameters that takes over 98% of importance.

The code is as below:

```
temp=pd.read_csv('temp_data.csv',sep=',',engine='python')
temp['y'] = temp['temp_actual']
y = temp['y'].values
temp = temp.drop(['y'],axis=1)

#X = temp.loc[:,:]
x= temp.values

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)
```

Please help correct the coding. Thanks!

Comment: You dropped `temp['y']` (a copy of `temp['temp_actual']`), but you still use `temp['temp_actual']` as a predictor.

Comment: Yup, that is the problem, How can I avoid using temp['temp_actual'] as a predictor? @DyZ Thank you!

Comment: Change `x= temp.values` to `x=temp[['col1','col2',...]]` where `col1`, etc are the names of the columns selected as predictors. (No need for `.values`.)

Comment: For dealing with tabular data like csv in Python the Pandas library is awesome. You can delete a column from a data from `df = pd.read_csv('temp_data.csv'); del df.column_name;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you made a copy of the target feature to column `y` by using the code

```
temp['y'] = temp['temp_actual']
```

Then you set `y` as the values in that column

```
y = temp['y'].values
```

You then dropped the column `y` from the data frame with the following code

```
temp = temp.drop(['y'],axis=1)
```

Now if you looked at the columns of the dataframe `temp` you can see that `y` is not present but `temp_actual` is there.

You have to remove that column from the dataframe, in order to do that you can do any of the following methods.

```
del temp['temp_actual']
```

OR

```
temp = temp.drop(['temp_actual'], axis=1)
```